# How to download all Android SDK platforms using sdkmanager from terminal without Android Studio?

Tags: command-line, android-sdk, android-studio

Need to automate downloading of all available Android SDK Platforms using the `sdkmanager` from terminal. For example, an Android SDK Platform 19 can be installed using `sdkmanager "platforms;android-19"`. How to install all avaiable SDK Platforms without running the command separately for each platform?

Comment: Hmm, I have a feeling this question is more about terminal scripting like perhaps doing some looping rather than about Android specifically, and I wonder if other sister sites about desktop PC (e.g. [su]) might be helpful...

Comment: All SDK plaforms can be downloaded by writing a script. I wanted to know if there is a flag or an option that can be given to `sdkmanager` to download all SDK platforms.

Comment: Given how big in disk size each platform can get, the manual/scripted use of `sdkmanager --list --channel=0` and then installing the ones you want may deliberate.